# Why I can't keep my session when I register

Tags: php, session

**customer_register.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
?>

 <form action="customer_register.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<?php

    if (isset($_POST['c_name']) && isset($_POST['c_email']) && isset($_POST['c_usrname']) && isset($_POST['c_password']) && isset($_POST['c_country']) && isset($_POST['c_city']) && isset($_POST['c_contact']) && isset($_POST['c_address']) && isset($_FILES['c_image']['name'])) {

        $c_ip_add = getIp();

        $c_name = $_POST['c_name'];
        $c_email = $_POST['c_email'];
        $c_username = $_POST['c_usrname'];
        $c_password = $_POST['c_password'];
        $c_country = $_POST['c_country'];
        $c_city = $_POST['c_city'];
        $c_contact = $_POST['c_contact'];
        $c_address = $_POST['c_address'];
        $c_image = @$_FILES['c_image']['name'];

        $c_tmp_name = @$_FILES['c_image']['tmp_name'];
        $location = 'customer/customer_images/';

        if (!empty($c_name) && !empty($c_email) && !empty($c_username) && !empty($c_password) && !empty($c_country) && !empty($c_city) && !empty($c_contact) && !empty($c_address) && !empty($c_image)) {
            move_uploaded_file($c_tmp_name, $location.$c_image);

            $select_user = "SELECT customers_username FROM customers WHERE customers_username = '$c_username'";

            $run_select_user = mysqli_query($conn, $select_user);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($run_select_user) == NULL) {

                $insert_customer = "INSERT INTO customers(customers_ip, customers_name, customers_email, customers_username, customers_pass, customers_country, customers_city, customers_contact, customers_address, customers_image) VALUES ('$c_ip_add', '$c_name', '$c_email', '$c_username', '$c_password', '$c_country', '$c_city', '$c_contact', '$c_address', '$c_image')";

                $run_insert_customer = mysqli_query($conn, $insert_customer);

                $select_cart = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '$c_ip_add'";

                $run_select_cart = mysqli_query($conn, $select_cart);

                $check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_select_cart);

                if ($check_cart == 0) {
                    $_SESSION['customer_email'] = $c_email;
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $c_username;
                    echo '<script>alert("Account has been successfully created")</script>';
                    echo '<script>window.open("customer/my_account.php","_self")</script>';
                } else {
                    $_SESSION['customer_email'] = $c_email; 
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $c_username;
                    echo '<script>alert("Account has been successfully created")</script>';
                    echo '<script>window.open("checkout.php","_self")</script>';
                }

            } else {
                echo "<div align='center' style='color:white; font-size:20px; padding:20px 0px;'><b>The Username already exists. Please try another username.</b></div>";
            }


        } else {
            echo "<div align='center' style='color:white; font-size:20px; padding:20px 0px;'><b>All Fileds are required</b></div>";
        }
    }


  ?>

<table align="center" width="750">

  <thead>
    <tr align="center">
      <th colspan="3"><h1>Create an Account</h1></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="label" align="right">Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="c_name" size="40" required></td>
    </tr>

     <tr>
        <td id="label" align="right">Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="c_email" size="40" required></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td id="label" align="right">Username:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="c_usrname" size="40" required></td>
     </tr>

     <tr>
        <td id="label" align="right">Password:</td>
        <td><input type="password" name="c_password" size="40" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="label" align="right">Image:</td>
        <td><input type="file" name="c_image" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td id="label" align="right">Country:</td>
      <td>
         <select name="c_country">
           <option size="50">Select Country</option>
              <?php countries(); ?>
         </select>

      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td id="label" align="right">City:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="c_city" size="40" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="label" align="right">Contact:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="c_contact" size="40" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td id="label" align="right">Address:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="c_address" size="40" required></td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
            <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="register" value="Create Account"></td>
    </tr>


    </tbody>

 </table>
</form>
```

**customer_login.php**

```
 <?php
   session_start();
  ?>

<form method="post" action="">

    <table width="500" align="center" bgcolor="skyblue">
        <thead>
            <tr align="center">
                <th colspan="4"><h2>Login or Register to Buy!</h2></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
           <tr>
              <td align="right"><b>Email:</b></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email"></td>
           </tr>

            <tr>
              <td align="right"><b>Password:</b></td>
              <td><input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Enter Password"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="4"><a href="checkout.php?forgot_pass">Forgot Password?</a></td>
            </tr>

            <tr align="center">
                <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></td>
            </tr>

         </tbody>
    </table>

    <h2 style="float:right; padding:10px;"><a href="customer_register.php" style="text-decoration:none;">New? Register Here</a></h2>

  </form>

 <?php

    if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['pass'])) {

    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $pass = $_POST['pass'];

    if (!empty($email) && !empty($pass)) {

        $select_id = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers_email = '$email' AND customers_pass = '$pass'";

        $run_select_id = mysqli_query($conn, $select_id);

        foreach ($run_select_id as $details) {
            $usrname = $details['customers_username'];
            $id = $details['customers_id'];
        }

        $num_run_select = mysqli_num_rows($run_select_id);

        if ($num_run_select == NULL) {
            echo '<script>alert("Invalid : Email/Password combination")</script>';
            exit();
        }
            $c_ip_add = getIp();

            $select_cart = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE ip_add = '$c_ip_add'";

            $run_select_cart = mysqli_query($conn, $select_cart);

            $check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_select_cart);

            if ($num_run_select > 0 AND $check_cart == 0) {
                $_SESSION['customer_email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $usrname;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

                echo "<script>alert('You Have Logged In Succesfully')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('customer/my_account.php','_self')</script>";
                exit();
            } else {
                $_SESSION['customer_email'] = $email;
                $_SESSION['username'] = $usrname;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

                echo "<script>alert('You Have Logged In Succesfully')</script>";
                echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";
            }

    } else {
        echo 'Please enter valid email ID';
    }
}

?>
```

**my_account.php**

```
<?php
   session_start();
 ?>

<ul id="categories">
    <?php
        $location = 'customer_images/';
        $usr_email = $_SESSION['customer_email'];
        $user_name = @$_SESSION['username'];
        $usr_id = $_SESSION['id'];

        $select_image = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customers_id = '$usr_id'";

        $run_image = mysqli_query($conn,$select_image);

        foreach ($run_image as $select_all_data) {
            $id = $select_all_data['customers_id'];

            $name = $select_all_data['customers_name'];

            $username = $select_all_data['customers_username'];
            $email = $select_all_data['customers_email'];
            $country = $select_all_data['customers_country'];
            $city = $select_all_data['customers_city'];                     
            $contact = $select_all_data['customers_contact'];
            $address = $select_all_data['customers_address'];

            $image = $select_all_data['customers_image'];
                echo "<li style=''><img src='$location$image' height='150' width='174' style='text-align:center; border:3px solid black; padding:4px; border-radius: 109px;'></li>";

         }


?>

<li><a href="my_account.php?my_orders">My Orders</a></li>
<li><a href="my_account.php?edit_account">Edit Account</a></li>
<li><a href="my_account.php?change_pass">Change Password</a></li>
<li><a href="my_account.php?delete_account">Delete Account</a></li>
<li><a href="../logout.php">Logout</a></li>
</ul>

</div> 

<div class="content_area2">

 <?php cart(); ?>

<div id="my_account_menu">
    <span>
      <?php

        if (isset($_SESSION['customer_email'])) {
        echo "Welcome <i style='color:orange;'>" . $_SESSION['username']. ' </i>';
        }

    ?>
    <?php

    if (!isset($_SESSION['customer_email'])) {
        echo "<a href='../checkout.php' style='color:white;'>Login</a>";
    } else {
        echo "<a href='../logout.php' style='color:orange;'>Logout</a>";
    }

    ?>

    </span>
    </div>

    <?php getIp(); ?>

        <div id="products_box">

    <?php

    if (!isset($_GET['my_orders']) && !isset($_GET['edit_account']) && !isset($_GET['change_pass']) && !isset($_GET['delete_account'])) {


    ?>

    <div style="text-align:center;">

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td id="label">Name : </td>
                    <td id="detail"><?php echo @$name; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="label">Username (Display Name) : </td>
                   <td id="detail"><?php echo @$username; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                  <td id="label">Email : </td>
                  <td id="detail"><?php echo @$email; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="label">City : </td>
                    <td id="detail"><?php echo @$city; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="label">Contact : </td>
                    <td id="detail"><?php echo @$contact; ?></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td id="label">Address : </td>
                    <td id="detail"><?php echo @$address; ?></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>

        </table>

    </div>

        <div style="padding:20px;"><b>You can see your orders by clicking this <a href="my_account.php?my_orders">link</a></b></div>
    <?php

   }

?>
```

The problem is when I login it is working fine but when I register the user it gives the error undefined

```
    $usr_id = $_SESSION['id'];
```

in my_account.php and all the information about the user is not displayed

**I HAVE STARTED THE SESSION**

Comment: Did you call `session_start();` at the top of the page where you are accessing the $_SESSION? It looks like you didn't. Add it and see if it helps

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: **Woah!** Wide open to SQL injection. Note that `mysqli_*` api isn't inherently secure.

Comment: I am just making this for my practice

Comment: This code is just a mass..

Comment: @Kalkran  I have session_start() in my code sorry I have not added this before but I have already this in my code

Comment: @OwaizYusufi it does not matter if you are a practising, you must start doing things correct on practice, then you will be perfect on productions

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile Ok I have Understand but please help me about this

Comment: why do you need to keep a session on registration? what are you gonna do with that session?

Comment: @Masivuye After registration I am sending the user to his/her account

Comment: Still you don't need a session for that,  you making simple things sound complicated.  Registration Process :

1. User fills in the form and supply email
2. Validate, Filter and sanitize the user inputs.
3. Prepare and execute query
4. If query successfully then send an email to the provided email address.

Comment: @Masivuye let me explain u if the user have selected the products and if he/she is a new customer so they should be redirected to the payment page else if he/she does not selected the products they should be redirected to my_account.php

Comment: so basically your users select products on registration?

Comment: @Masivuye no no he/she can select products without registration but if they want to checkout and he/she is a new customer so they have to register as happens and if they are not selected any products and they want to just make account for future then they should be redirected to the my_account.php after making the account

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I want to tell u that after registration the problem is occurs but when i logout the user and again log in the the error does not come

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forget to call **[session_start](https://secure.php.net/session_start)** before to do anything, even when there is no existing session.

```
<?php
session_start()
// your code...
```

You may want to look how it works with the **[basic example](https://secure.php.net/session_start#refsect1-function.session-start-examples)** from the **[session_start](https://secure.php.net/session_start)** function

As stated within the PHP **[session_start](https://secure.php.net/session_start)** documentation:

> To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputing anything to the browser.

So you may want to include this call after PHP opening tag `<?php` as I wrote above

Answer (score 1):

You have to initiate the session by using **session_start()** on every page where you want to use the session. And this is missing on **my_account.php**

Ex:

```
<?php
session_start();

// your code
```

Comment: I have session_start() in my_account.php

Comment: @OwaizYusufi You need it on all pages that is using `$_SESSION`, before any data is sent to the browser.

Comment: bro I have this session_started on all the pages which requires it

Comment: `customer_register.php` does not have `session_start();`

Comment: @Masivuye Cokile it is

Answer (score 0):

nowhere in your `customer_register.php` file do you actually set `$_SESSION['id']`.

in addition to this:

- there are no form tags around your register form, so its hard to see how any data is getting into the script anyway.
- your'e also silencing (`@`) errors.  If this is a learning task, which from your comments I assume it is, thats a very counterproductive thing to do.

As you only set `$_SESSION['id']` in the login handing script, its not going to be available across pages unless they go through that form.  Its hard to tell from your code what your'e intended user journey is, but as it stands at the moment it looks like your'e expecting them to register, then be able to see the account page as a logged in user.

Just set `$_SESSION['id']` in the register script, or dispense with it entirely and use the username (seeing as you validate it as unique anyway).

Also, your'e query in the `my_account.php` is looking for a column `customer_id` which (as far as I can see) you dont actually set in the `insert` statement.

This is the trouble with programming, it only does what you tell it to do.

Comment: bro I have set customer_id auto increment in my database

Comment: I am making shopping website as I am a new developer not very new but 11 months